# No hdd space left

Tags: hard-drive, disk-usage

I have 13.4Gb hdd space for my Ubuntu partition, and the only software that I use is Thunderbird, Firefox, and Play On Linux with MS Office 2010 (.playonlinux uses 2.6Gb). I can't use UbuntuOne because of the limited space I have left (currently only 400mb is used).

I don't store any files on my Ubuntu partition, but only from updating the OS I got down to only 87mb free space, 'megabites', not gigabites. I've run Bleachbit a few times in the last few months and it can only recover about 250mb each time. I've run Disk Usage Analyser, and it says that 4gb is used in home/.encryptfs/myname/.Private Really, I do not store any files on the computer itself, but make them available to both OSs on an external hard drive and usb memory sticks. I'm currently running 12.04 LTS (64bit), and currently I wouldn't be able to upgrade to 14.04 LTS with only this tiny bit of space left. How do I fix this?

Comment: Increase Ubuntu partition or replace Hard-drive with a bigger one!

Comment: According to http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support only 4.5Gb is required, and may be 2 or 3Gb for PlayonLinux with MS Office, which means I should have about 6Gb free. Also, what is the .encryptfs? It uses 4Gb! So, even if .encryptfs wasn't a problem, I should still have 2Gb free. It seems that something is seriously wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the package and dist updates, and online installations of applications, clearing the package cache and old Linux kernels could recover considerable hard disk space.

And to do the same, open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) use the the commands that follow:

1. To clean the package cache created by `apt` installations (i.e. remove all package archives cached in `/var/cache/apt/archives`):

   ```
   sudo apt-get clean
   ```
2. To remove all the older kernels but the currently used one:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge $(dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d')
   ```

*(Notes: **-a-** You can copy the above line of command combo and paste to the terminal. **-b-** Shortcut to paste in terminal is: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.)*

Comment: Thanks. I was able to remove over 2,800mb of files. After expanding the partition to about 21Gb (with new problems, now solved) checking Disk Use Analysis, it says I have 12.3Gb free space, but 11.2Gb available. AND, it still gave me a warning that I have just 1Gb of space left. It seems something is wrong somewhere.

Comment: ..could you please update your Q with the outputs of `sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /`, `sudo du -h --max-depth=3 /home` and `sudo fdisk -l`