# How do I do a Grub resuce?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

I've had a problem with hdd space, as detailed here: [No hdd space left](https://askubuntu.com/questions/408996/no-hdd-space-left)

I've since tried to make more space using GParted. I've deleted partitions I thought were not being used, and expanded my Ubuntu partion. So my partitions are
1. Dell
2. OS Recovery
3. Windows
4. Ubuntu

Five and six were other things I didn't know, and there was some unallocated space. A long time ago I tried to expand Ubuntu backwards to take up Windows territory, but it couldn't be done. So today I thought I'd try the other direction. Now I get this message after restarting:
  error: no such partiion.
  grub rescue>
How do I rescue grub? I have 12.04 on usb to use for gparted.

System: Dell Latitude E5520, Windows 7, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, total drive space was 300Gb, with about 200Gb free space in Windows, but could not use for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have Ubuntu Live CD or Live USB. Normal session can be used to repair the grub. Boot using your Ubuntu Live CD or Live USB, while booting choose Try Ubuntu.

Once booted then open a terminal, and run the following command one by one to install the boot repair.

To add boot-repair to the repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
```

To Update your repository

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To install boot-repair

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Once Installation complete run boot-repair on terminal by typing the following command or select it by System->Aministration->Boot Repair.

NOTE: Update the Boot Repair if its newer version is available.

It will scan the System for few seconds and will show you the options Recommended repair and Create a BootInfo summary. By clicking the Recommended Repair it will start repair the grub.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't have access to an active internet connection, you can issue `sudo grub-install /dev/sd(hard drive letter, usually a)` from the terminal, and that will reinstall GRUB onto the bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for your help, it's really appreciated. I'm able to get back into both Windows and Ubuntu, again. The only hitch was I had to change my USB starter disk to 64bit (my fault). After that the instructions worked well.